# Sophos Endpoint Security and Control -> windows event viewer logs (on windows 2008R2 / 2012R2)

Tags: anti-virus, event-viewer, sophos

I'm trying to understand if and how would it be possible to save / record Sophos Endpoint Security and Control related events / actions within the Windows Event Viewer Log -> where should I look / search for ? 
(basically, how to enable antivirus events / actions logging to Windows Event Viewer, under windows server 2008R2 and 2012R2)

I've tried to search on the sophos community / documentation without any success so far.

Any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Detections should go to the Windows Application Event log. E.g.:

- Event ID 36 - Virus/spyware 'EICAR-AV-Test' has been removed.
- Event ID 32 - File "C:\Users\em\Desktop\1.com" belongs to
  virus/spyware 'EICAR-AV-Test'.

Source: Sophos Anti-Virus

Level: Warning.

If you save the Eicar string (http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) to a file called "test.com" for example, you should see the on-access scanner detect and clean it up and the above events raised.